# If File path does not exits then exit sub

Tags: vba, excel, save

Hey I fairly new at Excel and I am running into a problem with error handing. I want my macro to run and if it can not find the folder then it should produce a message to the users and exit sub. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is my code on where my macro saves file

```
    Worksheets("Input data").Visible = True
    folder = "\\Group_SHARED\Group Shared\Engineering\Controlled Folder\Number_Checkout\Archived\Archived"
    MyTime = Time
    Sheets("Input data").Select
    Range("G2").Value = MyTime
    strFileName = folder & "_" & Sheets("Input data").Range("C6").Value & "_" & Sheets("Get_ECN").Range("B6").Value & "_" & Sheets("Input data").Range("C3").Value & " " & Sheets("Input data").Range("C4").Value
    Worksheets("Input data").Visible = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFileName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    If dir(folder) = "" then
       Msgbox "no such directory"
       Exit sub
    end if
```

as in:

```
Sub Test()
    folder = "C:\Users\Administrator\"
    If Dir(folder) = "" Then
       MsgBox "no such directory"
       Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "Yup, It's There All Right."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure your folder path ends with a "\" as in the above example. -This works fine for me. If it's not working on your end could you tell me what error messages you're getting? I may be able to help further.

Comment: In our office we are using a shared drive and even when I am connected to the share drive the macro still exits and returns the message "no such directory" and when I am disconnected to the share drive I get the error Run Time Error 52 Bad File Name or Number